# Scribd setPage function is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, viewer, scribd

I have integrated scribd document viewer to my website but setPage function is not working

Can you help me to view only the first 2 pages in the document please look into in the below

url and help me to find the solution.

```js
<div id='embedded_doc' ><a href='http://www.scribd.com'>Scribd</a></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var url = 'http://nskfix.com/dev/waleed/webupload/upload/2011_Dam-Sluice-Gate-Walkway-Slabs.pdf';
  var pub_id = 'pub-07535389025944280985849137';
  var scribd_doc = scribd.Document.getDocFromUrl(url, pub_id);

  var onDocReady = function(e){
    scribd_doc.api.setPage(1);
  }
 

  scribd_doc.addEventListener('docReady', onDocReady);
  /*scribd_doc.addParam('jsapi_version', 2);*/
  scribd_doc.addParam('height', 600);
  scribd_doc.addParam('width', 760);
  /*scribd_doc.addParam('public', true);*/
  
  scribd_doc.addParam( 'auto_size', true );
  scribd_doc.addParam('hide_disabled_buttons', true);
  scribd_doc.addParam('disable_resume_reading', true);
  scribd_doc.addParam( 'jsapi_version', 2 );
  scribd_doc.addParam( 'allow_share', false );

  scribd_doc.write('embedded_doc');
</script>
```

Comment: Show the code in the question instead of linking your site.

Answer (score 1):

This may be too late to answer your question but it might help somebody else.

I have the same problem but I can get it working by using the *seamless* method instead of *write*.

Replace:

```
scribd_doc.write('embedded_doc');
```

With:

```
scribd_doc.seamless('embedded_doc');
```

I think very few people are using the **JS API**.

Their own example isn't working at this time due to it trying to load the http version of thier API instead of the https version:
https://www.scribd.com/developers/js_api_example